# My code is working but with no outputs, what is the problem?

Tags: python, pycharm

What is the problem?

i even tried this at the starting soas to get a output

```py
print("enter list elements")
arr = input()


def AlternateRearr(arr, n):

    arr.sort()

    v1 = list()
    v2 = list()

    for i in range(n):
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0):
            v1.append(arr[i])

        else:
            v2.append(arr[i])

        index = 0
        i = 0
        j = 0
        Flag = False
 #set value to true is first element is even
        if (arr[0] % 2 == 0):
            Flag = True

#rearranging
        while(index < n):

            #if 1st elemnt is eevn
            if (Flag == True):
                arr[index] = v1[i]
                index += 1
                i+=1
                Flag = ~Flag

            else:
                arr[index] = v2[j]
                index +=1
                j += 1
                Flag = ~Flag


        for i in range(n):
            print(arr[i], end = "" )

            arr = [9, 8, 13, 2, 19, 14]
            n = len(arr)
            AlternateRearr(arr, n)
            print(AlternateRearr(arr))
```

There's no error.
Just the driver code dosen't work i guess, there's no output.

Answer (score 2):

> no outputs

The only place where it could output anything is `print(AlternateRearr(arr))`. But let's take a look at `AlternateRearr` itself - what does it return?

There's no return statement anywhere in `AlternateRearr`, so the `print` would show None. Well, it's *something*, not completely nothing...

---

But the code doesn't reach this part anyway - if it did, it would throw an error because `print(AlternateRearr(arr))` passes only one argument to the function `AlternateRearr` that takes 2 arguments. You don't have default value set for `n`, so it wouldn't work.

---

Okay, so we came to conclusion that we don't reach the `print` anyway. But *why*? Because you never call it. You only define it and it's a different thing from calling it.

You might encounter a problem if you just try calling it near your normal code - Python is an interpreted language, so your main-level code (not enclosed in functions) should be at the bottom of the file because it doesn't know anything that is below it.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your complete code?
Because you do have a function called `AlternateRearr` but you never call it

Answer (score 0):

Call the function and also pass the integer for iteration.
Add after the function:

```
AlternateRearr(arr, 5)
```